# How to render script in the head section using ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to render some script in the head section of an ASP.NET MVC view.
How can this be achieved?

In ASP.NET we had ContentPlaceHolders in Master. What is the MVC equivalent of implementing this?

Comment: @section, check [HERE](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `@section` like this:

**Master file**:

```cs
@RenderSection("masterjs", required: false)
```

**View file**:

```html
@section masterjs
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"></script> 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be otherway round? @RenderSection() in the master file(or in the _Layout.cshtml) and @section in the view file?

Comment: The answer is correct. The RenderSection is where the code/script is inserted which is in the layout file. The section describes what script should be inserted for a specific page. That way each page can insert a different script file into the head of the page.

Comment: What does required false mean?

Comment: "required: false" means the section is optional. If this is set to true you will get an error if it can't find the section it's looking for on your page